# Do likes and dislikes affect the order of video shown upon searching?

Tags: youtube, search

When we search for videos on YouTube, based upon keywords used for searching and title of videos, YouTube shows search results.

Now I want to know whether the order of results being displayed depends upon the likes and dislikes?

Since there may be many misleading or low quality videos I thought whether ratings can judge the quality and correctness like Stack Exchange has:

> **Why is voting important?**
>
> Voting is central to our model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how …
>
> ...good content rises to the top
> ...incorrect content falls to the bottom

Comment: What do you mean by " filtered on top upon searching"? Are you asking about YouTube's algorithm for the order in which they show search results?

Comment: @ale Yes, I mean how search results are shown (ordered).

Comment: I don't know that this question can be answered without people simply speculating. The algorithms that go into Google's search products are trade secrets that they're not going to share with mere mortals.

Comment: @ale oh! ok I just thought if we can moderate it by voting.

Answer (score 0):

Likes/Dislikes don't affect ranking, they do however affect whether more of your videos get featured to the user in the recommended sections. This goes contrary to what a lot of the online folks say, but is in line with what I've seen in the YouTube Certified course, have been told by community managers, and it is point 4 here: http://tubularinsights.com/10-youtube-seo-myths/